# How to make dropdown menu clickable?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a website where I need to have 15 HTML files. I made `navbar` with 3 direct links `nav-items` and 2 dropdowns.
How can I make dropdown does not show on click but shows on hover and sends me to dropdown `href` link when I click on it?

I tried to put `nav-item` class with `dropdown-menu` class but it does not working.

There is my navbar:

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logotxt.png" width="150"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-uppercase font-weight-bold small">
            <li class="nav-item mr-3 pr-3 border-right active">
              <a class="nav-link p-0 text-blue" href="index.html">Domov</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-3 pr-3 border-right dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link p-0 text-blue dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                O klubu
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">Dosežki</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">Zgodovina</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">Zanimivosti</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-3 pr-3 border-right text-blue">
              <a class="nav-link p-0 text-blue" href="#">Prva ekipa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-3 pr-3 border-right dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link p-0 text-blue dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Rezultati
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">Španska liga</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">Španski pokal</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">Liga prvakov</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-blue">
              <a class="nav-link p-0 text-blue" href="#">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You have to choose between click event for open/close or click event for browsing to an url. There is a third possibility, the double-click, but this is not user friendly in my opinion.

Comment: Can you check [link](https://www.realmadrid.com/) website. Navbar on that page has that option (you hover "ENTRADAS" and it shows dropdown, but you also can click "ENTRADAS" and it will open new page). Is that javascript or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You Want to Hover then

**Simple,** CSS only solution:

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

You can edit or preview [Here On JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st0uqz78/)

And

The `href` attribute specifies the link's destination:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a> <!-- Example -->
```

If you want to click whatever page suppose u want to click on About page then simply use like these

```
<a href="About.html">About</a>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I want to it shows me dropdown when I hover it, but when I click it it sends me to specific page.

Comment: u should design first that particular page after that u can link that page

Comment: You do not understand. It must send me to hash (#) link if I click on that, but it does not recognize my click at all.

Comment: your project directory share that directory image on post ...i want to see which file u have

Comment: Oh, I got it. have just added `nav-item` class in my dropdown and deleted everything other like `id`, `role`, `data-toggle` etc.